# Swagger UI Unable to infer popup All the time

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

I am using the tomcat 8.5.50 and my config classes are as below. I tried all the options that are available at stack overflow but  nothing seems to work. I am using 2.8.0 version of springfox.

```
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/api- 
          docs","/swagger.json").permitAll();
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll();
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll();
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
        httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.clearlane.docservice.web.rest"))
            //.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .pathMapping("/");
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
    
}
```

#Pom dependency :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you provide more information regarding either the error you are seeing, or the expected behaviour that you're not seeing ?

Comment: I am using tomact8.5.50 to deploy a springboot app with Swagger. I am able to see the v2/api-docs showing correctly. when I try to do the swagger-ui  then I am getting a popup saying Unable to infer ......  Any help is appriciated.